# Mosteller's First Ace Problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, simulation

[this probably belongs on cross validated ... ]

Working through Mosteller's Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Mathematica.  I am trying to understand Mosteller's answer for The First Ace problem (#40).  The problem goes:

> Shuffle an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards containing 4 aces.  Then turn up cards from the top until the first ace appears.  On the average how many cards are required to produce the first ace?

I solved this problem in Mathematica as as follows:

```
suite = Flatten@{Range[2, 10], J, Q, K, A}
deck = Flatten@{suite, suite, suite, suite}
dat = Table[First@Flatten@Position[
         RandomSample[deck, Length@deck], A], {n, 1, 100000}];
ListPlot[
    Tally@dat,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Gray],
    Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

```
Mean@dat // N
10.6152
```

Which yields Mosteller's answer (by symmetry) of 10.6 cards (48/5 +1).

I was a bit shocked that the mode was 1 card.

Finally, when I look at the CDF the 50% mark is at 8 cards

```
t = Reverse[SortBy[Tally@dat, #[[2]] &]][[All, 2]]
ListPlot[N[Accumulate@t/100000],
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Gray]
]
```

[image]

So my question is, if I played this game for real in a casino, should I go for 8 or 10 cards?

Comment: I think you're right, this probably belongs on CrossValidated... Cool problem though.

Comment: @MarcoB I believe this belongs here, because - next to the theoretical aspect - it shows how to make use of Mathematica's abilities to simulate and to work with its distribution-framework.

Comment: My bad, I corrected my "decision support" (cf. [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139628/764)): In the simple 0-1-Utility case (right/wrong and a fixed amount to win), you would best choose $1$ (not 8, not 10). My exmple meets the case, when you will win an amount equal to the number of draws it took.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to choose a slightly different approach here and point out, that this is an example for the [*Negative Hypergeometric Distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution). Wikipedia does give a nice table for this:

[image: Choice of distributions]

While for large numbers the distribution tends to the *Negative Binomial Distribution* the difference essentially is *drawing with replacements* (Binomial) vs. *drawing without replacements* (Hypergeometric).

### Analytical Approach

In the present case, even when we may not have remembered all this statistical theory, we could still take an analytical approach by making use of [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html). Let us look at the probabilities for the first few numbers of draws:

\begin{align}
p(1) &= p(\text{ace}) =\frac{4}{52} \\
p(2) &= p(\neg\text{ace}) \times p(\text{ace}) = \frac{52-4}{52} \times \frac{4}{52-1} \\
p(3) &= p(\neg\text{ace}) \times p(\neg\text{ace}) \times p(\text{ace}) = \frac{52-4}{52} \times \frac{52-4-1}{52-1} \times \frac{4}{52-2} \\
\vdots
\end{align}

So eventually we see a pattern here and can (hopefully) come up with the formula for the probability distribution function (in the discrete case a probability *mass* function) $f$ given the number of cards (or balls in an urn) $N$ and the number of marked cards (or balls) $M$:

\begin{align}
f_{N,M}(k) = \frac{m}{N-k+1} \times \prod \limits_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{N-M-i+1}{N-i+1}
\end{align}

To implment this as a distribution we write the following code:

```
distribution[ n_Integer, m_Integer ] /; m <= n := ProbabilityDistribution[

    m/( n - k + 1) Product[ (n - m - i + 1)/(n - i + 1),{ i, 1, k-1 } ],
    { k, 1, n - m + 1, 1 }
    (* , Method -> "Normalization" is not needed here, but may be worth remembering
       for all cases where giving a proportional formula is easy to come up with *) 
]

analyticalDist = distribution[ 52, 4 ];

$PlotTheme = {"Detailed", "LargeLabels"};

Panel @ DiscretePlot[ 
    Evaluate@PDF[ analyticalDist, \[FormalX] ], 
    {\[FormalX], 0, 49, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Analytical PDF", "Subsection"]
]
```

[image: Analytical PDF]

Also we can find moments and what have you:

```
Mean @ analyticalDistribution (* e.g. the expected number of draws *)
```

> $\frac{53}{5}$

### Empirical Approach

We could of course also arrive at answers using *simulation*:

```
empiricalDist = EmpiricalDistribution @ Table[ 
    Min @ RandomSample[ Range[52], 4], 
    {10000} (* number of trials *)
];

N @ Mean @ empiricalDist
```

> 10.5809 (* true value again was 10.6 *)

If we compare the graphs for the PDF we note that the empirical distribution already is quite close:

```
Panel @ DiscretePlot[
    Evaluate @ {
        PDF[ empiricalDist, \[FormalX] ],
        PDF[ analyticalDist, \[FormalX] ]
    },
    { \[FormalX], 1, 49, 1 },
    PlotLegends -> {"empirical", "analytical"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["PDF Comparison", "Subsection"]
]
```

[image: Comparison of PDFs]

### General Case: Negative Hypergeometric Distribution

Grabbing a text book near you, you will find the formula for the probability distribution function of the above mentioned *Negative Hypergeometric Distribution*. It is a special case of the [`BetaBinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaBinomialDistribution.html) - thanks to @ciao for pointing this out repeatedly until I listened :) - for those of you, who do not know this, there is a terrific paper showing the relations between univariate distributions by [(*Leemis and McQueston 2008*)](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf) and more information can be found on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85859/36678).

Using this information, we can implement the *Negative Hypergeometric Distribution* explicitly as follows:

```
(* following Mathematica's parametrization for the hyergeometric case *)
negativeHypergeometricDistribution[k_, m_, n_ ] := TransformedDistribution[
    \[FormalX] + 1,
    \[FormalX] \[Distributed] BetaBinomialDistribution[ k, m, n-m ]
]

(* unfortunately parametrization is no standardized so one has to dwelve into
   the formulae for this in the paper, which are given though *)

nhg = negativeHypergeometricDistribution[ 1, 4, 52 ];

Mean @  nhg
```

> $\frac{53}{5}$

And we can indeed convince ourselves that our case simply is a special case of a NHG-distributed random var $X$, where $X$ is the number of draws from $N = 52$ cards, where $M=4$ are "successes" and where we need $k=1$ success to stop:

```
And @@ Table[ PDF[ analyticalDist, i ] === PDF[ nhg, i ], {i, 1, 52 } ]
```

> True

### EDIT: Decision Support / Expected Utility

The OP has edited his question and asked for guidance in playing at a casino (e.g. what number of draws to *bet on*?). For this we have to turn to *decision theory* and *excepted utility*.

Let's assume that you are risk neutral. In the case that you get a fixed amount if you are right and zero if you are wrong, then it would be trivially optimal to bet on $1$. ($1$ has the greatest probability and the 0-1-loss function makes the expected utility equal to the probability; check this by simulation!)

Let us look at a more elaborate case to make the principle clear: If you were to receive the number of draws needed worth in money if you bet on the right number of draws, then your utility function would be $U(x,k) = x I(x = k)$ (where $I$ is the indicator function, $x$ your bet and $k$ the number of draws it took. In this case your best bet will be $13$:

```
NArgMax[ 
    {
        NExpectation[ 
          \[FormalX] * Boole[ \[FormalX] == i], 
          \[FormalX] \[Distributed] negativeHypergeometricDistribution[ 1, 4, 52 ]
        ],
        1<= k<= 49
    }, 
    k ∈ Integers
]
```

> 13

```
With[
    {
        dist =  negativeHypergeometricDistribution[ 1, 4, 52 ]
    },
    Panel @ DiscretePlot[ Evaluate@ Expectation[ 
          \[FormalX] * Boole[ \[FormalX] == i ], 
          \[FormalX] \[Distributed] dist 
        ], 
        {i,1,49}, 
        ImageSize -> Large, 
        PlotLabel -> Style["Expected Utility (0-1)", "Subsection"],
        PlotLegends->None
    ]
]
```

[image: Expected Utility]

Comment: "since it is not implemented...". It is, as `BetaBinomial`, already noted in an earlier reply.

Comment: @ciao Thanks, I did not make that connection. It is deeply burried in the docs and also not very obvious from web research. Guess one really needs to know what your looking for. :)

Comment: Not so much an MMA docs issue, more of a wider issue of distributions going by different names/definitions in the mathematical world. Would be nice if a future MMA docs edition (or MathWord) had a big interconnected chart with *all* alternate names/definitions and their relationships...

Comment: This is the best [overview with regard to the relationships between univariate distributions](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf) I have found so far.

Answer (score 4):

**Update (attribution: @ciao)**

As @ciao has pointed out, use of[`BetaBinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaBinomialDistribution.html)
is the most straightforward for exact calculation and simulation. See the comment:

```
Mean[BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 4, 48]] + 1
```

or simulation

```
Mean[RandomVariate[Mean[BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 4, 48]] + 1],100000]
Median[RandomVariate[Mean[BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 4, 48]] + 1],100000]
```

etc

**Original Answer**

As the choice of first Ace is arbitrary you could simplify, e.g.:

```
tab = Table[Min[FirstPosition[RandomSample[Range[52]], #][[1]] & /@ Range[4]], 
   10000];
Histogram[tab, Automatic, "PDF"]
N@Mean[tab]
Median[tab]
```

[image]

You could also do analytically,e.g. let $f(k)$ be the probability that the first ace in the first $k$ cards, then:

```
f[k_] := 1 - Binomial[52 - k, 4]/Binomial[52, 4]
DiscretePlot[f[k], {k, 0, 52}]
```

Sanity checks:$f(k)=1$ for $k\ge 49$

The probability that is $k$th card is discrete derivative:

```
ListPlot[Differences[Table[f[k], {k, 0, 52}]], Filling -> Axis]
Differences[Table[f[k], {k, 0, 52}]].Range[52]
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could just `Mean[BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 4, 48]] + 1...` ;=}

Comment: @ciao doh! always forgetting to exploit diverse built-in distributions...hope your entrepreneurship is going well ;-)